# Setting global properties in Composed Task which would be accessible in each of subtasks

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

##### Setting 'common' properties for child tasks is not working

The SCDF version I'm using is 2.9.6.

I want to make CTR A-B-C, each of tasks does follows:

`A : sql select on some source DB`

`B : process DB data that A got`

`C : sql insert on some target DB`

Simplest way to make this work seems to define shared work directory folder Path "some_work_directory", and pass it as application properties to A, B, C. Under {some_work_directory}, I just store each of task result as file, like `select.result`, `process.result`, `insert.result`, and access them consequently. If there is no precedent data, I could assume something went wrong, and make tasks exit with 1.

###### ================

I tried with a composed task instance `QWER`, with two task from same application "global" named as `A`, `B`. This simple application prints out `test.value` application property to console, which is "test" in default when no other properties given.

If I tried to set test.value in global tab on SCDF launch builder, it is interpreted as `app.*.test.value` in composed task's log. However, SCDF logs on child task A, B does not catch this configuration from parent. Both of them fail to resolve input given at launch time.

If I tried to set test.value as row in launch builder, and pass any value to A, B like I did when task is not composed one, this even fails. I know this is not 'global' that I need, it seems that CTR is not working correctly with SCDF launch builder.

The only workaround I found is manually setting `app.QWER.A.test.value=AAAAA` and `app.QWER.B.test.value=BBBBB` in launch freetext. This way, input is converted to `app.QWER-A.app.global4.test.value=AAAAA, app.QWER-B.app.global4.test.value=BBBBB`, and print well.

I understand that, by this way, I could set detailed configurations for each of child task at launch time. However, If I just want to set some 'global' that tasks in one CTR instance would share, there seems to be no feasible way.

Am I missing something? Thanks for any information in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTR will orchestrate the execution of a collection of tasks. There is no implicit data transfer between tasks. If you want the data from A to be the input to B and then output of B becomes the input of C you can create one Task / Batch application that have readers and writers connected by a processor OR you can create a stream application for B and use JDBC source and sink for A and C.